# What is this ternary operator condition here (true ? x : 0)

Tags: c#, conditional-operator, ternary

I am not able to understand the question and output here. I am well aware of the basic syntax of the ternary operator.
condition? statement 1: statement 2
if the condition is true then statement 1 otherwise statement 2.

But what's the condition in the problem given below? (true  ? x : 0) What is the program checking to be true?

```
using System;
public class Program
    {      
      public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          char x = 'A';
           int i = 0;
          Console.WriteLine (true  ? x : 0);  //Output: 65
          Console.WriteLine(false ? i : x);   //Output: 65
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's checking whether `true` is true. (Spoiler alert: `true` is always true)

Comment: A condition evaluates to true or false. Here that evaluation is already done

Answer (score 1):

I think this code isn't really checking something. The 'true' and 'false' are used to override the condition and execute the respective conditions.

```
Console.WriteLine (true  ? x : 0)
```

This straightaway executes the first statement. Had there been false here, statement 2 would be executed. Same goes for the other one.

Comment: Can you explain the output of this question to me. Why is the output 65,65?

Comment: Since the variable x has value as character 'A', it prints the ASCII value for A which is 65. The second time, 65 is printed for the next line of code. This might help:  [link](https://theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/capital-letter-a-uppercase-ascii-code-65.html)